# App engine Google cloud

Tags: ios, objective-c

I used parse framework for iOS sync framework.  Is there any framework in Google cloud. Went through app engine and only got tutorial on push notification. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the Mobile Backend Starter?
https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/mobile-backend-starter

Comment: Saw to it. But they have not given any example regarding how to get started. For iOS they have given push notification example. But i want   a simple thing here. I have some data in local database want to store it in cloud at some point and to fetch from there. How to achieve it?